# Alternatives to getting url of iframe

Tags: django, iframe

I'm building a website where the users to essentially "mark" things from another site -- e.g. they browse a third party's catalog, and once they hit an item they like, they somehow indicate to my site about that specific item (e.g. via the url). My initial thought was to have an iframe, a "mark" button on my own site in a little bar at the top, and the third party site in the iframe -- however, I found that it's impossible to get the url of an iframe if the user navigates away from the inital url. Is there any alternative to doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve html from another site, modify it and show to your user. Sure, you should have a grant from site owner and update your modifier for any html layout update. And you will need to resolve somehow all links from the page, including css, js and so on.

Iframe is not an option, you can't control the page in a frame in any way. That's security policy for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

(I know I'm a bit late but may be someone find it useful)

I had the same problem. I came to conclusion that only way to do that is creating proxy in PHP. And that's what I did (contents of "proxy.php" file):

```
<?php

$proxy = 'http://yoursite.com/proxy.php';
$host = parse_url($_GET['url'], PHP_URL_HOST);
$dir  = $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT].'/cache_proxy/'.$host;
if(!is_dir($dir))
    mkdir($dir);
$filepath = $dir.'/'.md5($_GET['url']);

if(is_file($filepath)){
    include($filepath);
}else{
    $page = file_get_contents($_GET['url']);


    $page = preg_replace('/(a href)=[\'\"](http.*)[\'\"]/', '$1="'.$proxy.'?url=$2"', $page);
    $page = preg_replace('/(a href)=[\'"][^http](.*)[\'"]/', '$1="'.$proxy.'?url=http://'.$host.'/$2"', $page);
    $page = preg_replace('/(href|src)=[\'"][^http+](.*)[\'"]/', '$1="http://'.$host.'/$2"', $page);

    file_put_contents($filepath, $page);

    echo $page;
}?>
```

Now you can insert iframe with src="`http://yoursite.com/proxy.html?url=http://othersite.com`"